# ¿Existe alguna forma de ejecutar en un servidor online una terminal sin necesidad de mantener mi dispositivo encendido?

Tags: python, servidor, godaddy

Estoy hospedado en GoDaddy desde hace un año, compré almacenamiento en un servidor y un dominio. Me puedo conectar sin problemas en el servidor desde ssh con putty. Se me ocurrió instalar python ahí mismo y empecé a ejecutar algunas herramientas matemáticas de python que he hecho. Y se me ha ocurrido tratar de calcular las máximas cifras posibles de **PI** en el servidor con python. Y aquí viene la pregunta, ¿puedo ejecutar una terminal o python en mi servidor con mi computadora apagada? O sea, que se ejecute online mientras yo esté durmiendo o haciendo otras actividades y para no gastar electricidad con mi dispositivo.

De antemano agradezco su apoyo. Saludos!

Comment: Si el servidor corre Linux, puedes usar `screen` en el servidor para iniciar una sesión "inmortal". Puedes desconectarte del servidor y la sesión seguira corriendo. Puedes reconectarte más tarde a la misma sesión aún corriendo. Otras alternativas: tmux, nohup.

Comment: Interesante. Lo voy a probar ahora mismo! Gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Del Contrato de Servicios:

> Prohibimos el uso de software o códigos en nuestros servidores que ocasionen que la carga del servidor supere el nivel razonable, según lo determinamos. Acepta que nos reservamos el derecho de eliminar su sitio web de forma temporal o permanente de nuestros servidores si está en violación de este contrato de servicios o existen actividades que amenazan la estabilidad de nuestra red.

Es decir, no deberías; podrías -tal vez por un tiempo- mientras no lo consideren una actividad abusiva que viole  alguna política de *Uso justo*, sobre todo si es un servicio de recursos compartidos.
Si es por recursos limitados, tal vez tengas mayor capacidad de cómputo en tu computadora. Y si pagas lo suficiente para recursos dedicados probablemente nadie se queje.